# Serialization using serialVersionUid

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, serialversionuid

As of now I am clear with the concept of serialization as well as the use of serialVersionUid. I have a doubt and would appreciate you all in helping me understand this scenario. Tried a lots but not getting appropriate help from Google.

1)Sender serializes an Object with a `serialVersionUid`

2)Receiver deserializes the same Object.

Where does the `serialVersionUid` come from?I suppose `JVM` will extract it from the serialized class. So is the receiver expected to have the same class loaded in memory, before deserializing? If then why there would be an Exception because of `serialVersionUid` mismatch, since the receiver will extract the `serialVersionUid` from the serialized class. And if this is the case, then why would we require `serialVersionUid` at all?

Comment: is the receiver expected to load class in memory before deserializing?

Comment: It appears you have answered your own question. "the receiver expected to have the same class" so if there is a version mismatch it will complain the `serialVersionUid` is different.

Comment: You can't use a class before it is loaded.